# Certain condition on an entire function implies the function is constant ?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f=u+iv$ be an entire function such that $v \ge 2u+1$ , then is it true that $f$ is constant ?

Comment: Yes. Use Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $f(z)=u+iv$, $g(z)=\exp((2+i)f(z))$. Then we have $|g(z)|=\exp(2u-v)\leq \exp(-1)$, and we finish easily.

Answer (score 2):

It's true. Let $g$ be a bijective holomorphic map which send $\{x+iy \in \mathbb C: y \geq 2x+1\}$ onto the unit disc. Then $g\circ f$ is entire and bounded, thus is constant. Thus $f$ is also constant.

(question: Is there such a holomorphic map $g$?)

Remark: The map $h(z) = e^{-i\theta} (z-i)$, where $\theta = \tan^{-1} 2$ is a linear map which send $\{x+iy \in \mathbb C: y \geq 2x+1\}$ onto the upper half plane.

Comment: Yes , the boundedness is the only problem why I couldn't apply Liouville directly ; please elaborate on the existence of $g$

Comment: @user123733: Do you know how to find a bijective holomorphic map from the upper half plane to the unit disc?

Comment: $\dfrac {z-1}{z+1}$ where $z$ is from upper half plane ?

Comment: @user123733: Great. Then first find a linear function $h(z) = az+b$ which send $\{y\geq 2x+1\}$ to the upper half plane. Then $g = p \circ h$, where $p$ is the function in your comment.

Comment: I am not able to find such a linear function :(

Comment: I have edited the answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another (almost equivalent) method in, $0$ is not in the image of the function and there is $r>0$ such that the disc $D_r=\{z\ :\ |z|<r\}$ is not either.

For example, take $r=1/4$: if $|z|<1/4$, then, $z=x+iy$ with $|x|,|y|<1/4$, so
$3/4\geq|y-2v|$, hence it is impossible that $y\geq 2x+1$ when $x+iy=z\in D_{1/4}$.

Now, take $g=1/f$. This is a holomorphic entire function. We know that $|f|>1/4$, therefore $|g|<4$, so by Liouville's theorem, $g$ is constant and so is $f$.